# search 'string1' or 'string2' in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

Search Box Logic based on user input:- [string1, string2, string3] where RESULT if all 3 strings are found > any 2 strings are found > any one string is found.

To perform custom search logic in Mongodb:- 
a) Is it possible using mongoosejs? or
b) Do i write javascript logic ?

Are there mongoose plugins for search box logic?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions, and don't seem to have tried anything on your own? What have you tried? Also ... "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @WiredPrairie. I'd be happy to discuss question for question. This is a specific programming question, which is answerable. As you can see from the answer below. Also it helps subsequent users who come to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search is straightforward although note that real full-text style search requires some additional reading and is a separate challenge.

```
var query = MyModel.find({$or: [{name: string1},{name: string2},{name: string3}]});
```

Sorting based on how many matched is not something I know how to do within mongodb itself. I don't think it's possible but maybe someone else knows how. I think that you will have to do in your application javascript logic.